# Odoo website template put selection field

Tags: odoo

Is there any way to put into website template Selection field (fields.Selecton) of some model or dropdown selection of some model records ?
Or only one way is to call some python methods and get some data and then put it data into web page using JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that you can add field using editor.
Also all fields are in the black list for website posting by default. To remove it from blacklist you will need to do stuff like this:

```xml
<function model="ir.model.fields" name="formbuilder_whitelist">
    <value>crm.lead</value>
    <value eval="[
        'contact_name',
        'description',
        'email_from',
        'name',
        'partner_name',
        'phone',
    ]"/>
</function>
```